# GraphQL String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql

I know there are so many questions about this issue, but I honestly can't understand any of the answers.

What I understand is that everything happens at build time, and my code supports that.

What I want, is to access a folder that is the same name as the field "slug" in my data. I create the pages in the gatsby-node.js file.

Here is my code for that:

gatsby-node.js

```js
exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
    const data = require("./src/data/data.json")
    const { createPage } = actions
    data.forEach(data => {
        createPage({
            path: `/${data.slug}/`,
            component: require.resolve('./src/templates/listing-template.js'),
            context:{data},
        })
    })
    
  }
```

I send the data in the context.

Now in my component, I want that data to be used in the query to get the specific folder for that page:

**listing** contains the data, and in **filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq:** I want to use it;

I have tried: `${listing.slug}` but graphql won't allow it inside the eq.

How can I do this?

The query just takes all the files from the specified folder

```
const Listing2 = ({listing}) => {
  
  const { casape } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allFile(
          sort: { fields: name, order: DESC }
          filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq: "casape" } }
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
```

I then use those returned images to create a gallery by the way.

What I tried:

```js
const Listing2 = ({listing}) => {
  
  const query = `
  query {
    allFile(
      sort: { fields: name, order: DESC }
      filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq: "casape" } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `
  query.replace("casape", listing.slug)

  const { allPhotos } = useStaticQuery(graphql`${query}`)
```

I also tried using the method
`graphQl(query, parameters: {slug : listing.slug}}`

and did

```
query Name($id = String!){
    allFile(
      sort: { fields: name, order: DESC }
      filter: { relativeDirectory: { eq: $id
 } }
```

But I get undefined.

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely use a parameterised query and pass `listing.slug` as a parameter. The proper syntax for that would be `query Name($slug: String!) { … }` though

Comment: Are you sure that `graphql` is imported from `graphql-tag`? it looks like Gatsby has it's own `graphql` package. It also looks like you can't pass variables to `useStaticQuery`. You may need to use a `pageQuery` for what you need to do. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/#differences-between-page-queries--static-queries